# How Do I split a SQL Server 2008 XML result into individual files in SSIS

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, ssis

The source query returns the XML I need in one variable. In SSIS how do I take that variable returned by the OLE adapter and split it out on each top level leaf into a file. In the case of my sample data I want to start a new file for the submission type tag but the file name will be the date and Patient ID. So a new file for every patient.

Sample data.

```
<submission type="HOSPITAL" data="CLINICAL" version="1.0" action-code="ADD">
    <provider>
        <provider-id>120129</provider-id>
        <patient>
            <birthdate>07-26-1925</birthdate>
            <sex>F</sex>
            <race>1</race>
            <ethnic>N</ethnic>
            <postal-code>32142</postal-code>
            <episode-of-care measure-set="PN">
                <admit-date>09-13-1987</admit-date>
                <discharge-date>09-14-1988</discharge-date>
                <pthic/>
                <patient-id>7228</patient-id>
                <detail answer-code="3" row-number="0" question-cd="ANOTHERINF"/>
                <detail answer-code="Y" row-number="0" question-cd="ANTIALLERGY"/>
            </episode-of-care>
        </patient>
    </provider>
</submission>
<submission type="HOSPITAL" data="CLINICAL" version="1.0" action-code="ADD">
    <provider>
        <provider-id>168729</provider-id>
        <patient>
            <birthdate>07-26-1835</birthdate>
            <sex>F</sex>
            <race>1</race>
            <ethnic>N</ethnic>
            <postal-code>39142</postal-code>
            <episode-of-care measure-set="PN">
                <admit-date>09-13-1986</admit-date>
                <discharge-date>09-14-1987</discharge-date>
                <pthic/>
                <patient-id>888</patient-id>
                <detail answer-code="3" row-number="0" question-cd="ANOTHERINF"/>
                <detail answer-code="Y" row-number="0" question-cd="ANTIALLERGY"/>
            </episode-of-care>
        </patient>
    </provider>
</submission>
```

Comment: So given the above set, you would expect two files containing the contents of the submission, named as patient_id and discharge-date?

Answer (score 1):

Warning: This answer is all [theoretical](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/MikeDavis/ssis/148/ssis-for-each-node-list-enumerator) at this point.  I will try to do it myself tonight because I find the question intriguing and I could see a future point when a project of our own might need to do something similar.  Plus I like learning new approaches for SSIS.

Anyway, here is my theory.

Foreach Loop Container

- Change Enumerator of the Collection to Foreach NodeList Enumerator
- Change Document source to your XML (either in form of variable, or query result or whatever)
- Change OuterXPathString to //Submission
- Have the loop pass the inner content of the xml to a flat file destination through the dataflow
- Also need to extract element properties from `Sumission` along the way

Like I said, this is theoretical - there might be some gotcha's that I'm not thinking of but I will get back in the next 24 hours or so with a working prototype (unless someone else comes along with a better answer).

Comment: FWIW, my approach would be similar except I think you'll want an inner Foreach enumerator to pluck out the values for the file name bits.

Comment: Well, so far my theoretical approach is working up to a point.  I'm having trouble with it stripping the markup and giving me element values only.  Now I'm committed tho - good brain teaser for SSIS.

Comment: I am getting ready to jump into this. Thanks for the insight. I've never done much with XML so I have to learn the terminology.

Comment: I am a little stuck on how to pass the inner content to a flat file through the dataflow.  Or was I not supposed to use an execute SQL task in the control flow

Comment: You can store it to a string variable and the ask for it again inside of the dataflow.

Comment: Also, as a follow up - when I was playing around with this myself I decided it would be easier to just script the whole thing out via a script task, string manipulation, and using the streamwriter in the System.IO namespace http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.aspx to break up the XML file and write it out to disk.